# save textipnput data to firebase using react-native for mobile app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to save the form values to firebase for a while now, but it is not going through. Please if you can help, please help. this is what i have done so far.

```
// SignUp.js
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/auth';
import "@firebase/database";
//import {app,db} from '../config';
import { db } from '../config';
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import {Alert, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button } from 'react-native';

let addItem = (Name,Password,Email) => {  
      db.ref('/items').push({
        name: Name,
        password:Password,
        email:Email
      });
    };

export default class SignUp extends Component {
  state = { 
            email: '', 
            password: '', 
            name:'',
            errorMessage: null 
          };


  handleSubmit = () => {
    addItem(this.state.name,
            this.state.password,
            this.state.email
            );
    alert('Item saved successfully');
  };


render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Sign Up</Text>
        {this.state.errorMessage &&
          <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>
            {this.state.errorMessage}
          </Text>}
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Email"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
          value={this.state.email}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Name"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
          value={this.state.name}
        />
        <TextInput
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
          value={this.state.password}
        />
        <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={this.handleSubmit} />
        <Button
          title="Already have an account? Login"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

my db config file is being called from another config file.
I have confirmed the config file and the link to the database and it is working. i have used it on another addFile.js and it worked fine. so please guys, i will appreciate if someone can help me with this. If there is a suggestion on any material on getting by with react-native and firebase, i will appreciate that. If firebase is not the best for me(because i am working on an investment app, i will like to get suggestions to other databases to use like mongodb and reference materials on how to get started.)

Answer (score 2):

Hi the easiest way for you to handle a signup would be by using firebase authentication this allows you to create a user with firebase and to store all this data securely. You could always access it later on and save it in different places. (Make sure the email authentication is enabled in firebase authentication)

```
  handleSubmit = () => {
    firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
  .then((user) => {
    if(user.user) {
      user.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: this.state.name
      }).then(() => {
          alert('Item saved successfully');
        })
    }
  })
  .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }));
};
```

after this is done you could later on access the user data as follow

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var postsRef = ref.child("/items/");
var newPostRef = postsRef.push();
newPostRef.set({
    name: user.displayName,
    email: user.email
});
```

user will now hold all the data you need going forward. Mind you that the password will not be accessible to you as it is hashed and should never be saved in the database just like this. Thats why firebase restrict access to it. I have used one of the examples for you, you could find more on push here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Comment: i want to know how to store other user entries to firebase, its not just about signup with email and password. let say i want my clients to signup with their client code and phone number, how do i go about it. or lets say i wan't to include otp which would be sent to their phone during login, how do i go about it. so the idea is sending and retrieving values from firebase. 
Thanks alot for the second part of your answer, it has solved a big problem for me.

Comment: Hi if this is a valid answer please add the V for future users